# Connecting iMac 2012 to an Yamaha Amplifier

Tags: imac

I just bought a 2012 iMac and I want to connect it to my Yamaha Amplifier.

On my previous PC setup I had an external audio card which connected to the Amplifier via an optical cable. However, I don't want to use an external card anymore.

What are my options? Does the iMac have an optical out? Is it via the Headphone/Audio Line-Out Port?

If so, do I connect it directly to the optical port of the Amplifier or do I have to also buy a DAC?

Regards,

Valentin Ivanov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the iMac have optical out, most Macs do.

You need one of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002MQGRM) Toslink adapter that plugs into standard 3.5mm audio plug for iMac to output optical from that.

Those are pretty cheap, and most are bundled with the cable itself or some audio accessories. Some shops might give away one for free, I got mine that way.

Anyway, Good luck!

Comment: So, with that setup I would directly connect the iMac to the Amplifier, no DAC needed?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that myself, connecting both my MacBook Pro and iMac to a Panasonic receiver.